# negative timestamp in installed ssm patches list of EC2 instance

Tags: python-2.7, amazon-web-services, boto3

I want to get all the installed patches on an `AWS EC2 instance`, So I run this code in `boto3`:

```
response = client.describe_instance_patches(InstanceId=instance_id, Filters=[{'Key': 'State','Values': ['Installed',]} ])
```

My instance has a patch with a negative timestamp :

```
    {
        "Patches": [
            {
                "KBId": "KB3178539",
                "Severity": "Important",
                "Classification": "SecurityUpdates",
                "Title": "Security Update for Windows 8.1 (KB3178539)",
                "State": "Installed",
                "InstalledTime": 1483574400.0
            },
            {
                "KBId": "KB4493446",
                "Severity": "Critical",
                "Classification": "SecurityUpdates",
                "Title": "2019-04 Security Monthly Quality Rollup for Windows 8.1 for x64-based Systems (KB4493446)",
                "State": "Installed",
                "InstalledTime": 1555804800.0
            },
            {
                "KBId": "KB4487080",
                "Severity": "Important",
                "Classification": "SecurityUpdates",
                "Title": "2019-02 Security and Quality Rollup for .NET Framework 3.5, 4.5.2, 4.6, 4.6.1, 4.6.2, 4.7, 4.7.1, 4.7.2 for Windows 8.1 (KB4487080)",
                "State": "Installed",
                "InstalledTime": -62135596800.0
            }
        ]

}
```

So my boto3 snippet gives me this error:

```
    response = client.describe_instance_patches(InstanceId=instance_id, Filters=[{'Key': 'State','Values': ['Installed',]}, ])
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/botocore/client.py", line 357, in _api_call
    return self._make_api_call(operation_name, kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/botocore/client.py", line 648, in _make_api_call
    operation_model, request_dict, request_context)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/botocore/client.py", line 667, in _make_request
    return self._endpoint.make_request(operation_model, request_dict)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/botocore/endpoint.py", line 102, in make_request
    return self._send_request(request_dict, operation_model)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/botocore/endpoint.py", line 135, in _send_request
    request, operation_model, context)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/botocore/endpoint.py", line 167, in _get_response
    request, operation_model)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/botocore/endpoint.py", line 218, in _do_get_response
    response_dict, operation_model.output_shape)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/botocore/parsers.py", line 242, in parse
    parsed = self._do_parse(response, shape)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/botocore/parsers.py", line 740, in _do_parse
    parsed = self._handle_json_body(response['body'], shape)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/botocore/parsers.py", line 761, in _handle_json_body
    return self._parse_shape(shape, parsed_json)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/botocore/parsers.py", line 302, in _parse_shape
    return handler(shape, node)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/botocore/parsers.py", line 572, in _handle_structure
    raw_value)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/botocore/parsers.py", line 302, in _parse_shape
    return handler(shape, node)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/botocore/parsers.py", line 310, in _handle_list
    parsed.append(self._parse_shape(member_shape, item))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/botocore/parsers.py", line 302, in _parse_shape
    return handler(shape, node)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/botocore/parsers.py", line 572, in _handle_structure
    raw_value)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/botocore/parsers.py", line 302, in _parse_shape
    return handler(shape, node)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/botocore/parsers.py", line 589, in _handle_timestamp
    return self._timestamp_parser(value)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/botocore/utils.py", line 558, in parse_timestamp
    return datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(value, tzlocal())
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/dateutil/tz/_common.py", line 144, in fromutc
    return f(self, dt)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/dateutil/tz/_common.py", line 258, in fromutc
    dt_wall = self._fromutc(dt)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/dateutil/tz/_common.py", line 222, in _fromutc
    dtoff = dt.utcoffset()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/dateutil/tz/tz.py", line 216, in utcoffset
    if self._isdst(dt):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/dateutil/tz/tz.py", line 288, in _isdst
    if self.is_ambiguous(dt):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/dateutil/tz/tz.py", line 250, in is_ambiguous
    (naive_dst != self._naive_is_dst(dt - self._dst_saved)))
OverflowError: date value out of range
```

I need to get the installed patches of several instances and I don't want the script to break when it finds a negative timestamp. How can workaround this ? How can I use the filters to get only valid timestamps ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got this working by using `subprocess` with `aws cli` instead of `boto3`:

```
response = subprocess.Popen(["aws", "ssm", "describe-instance-patches", "--instance-id", instance_id, "--filters","Key=State,Values=Installed", "--profil", "prod", "--output", "json"], stdout=subprocess.PIPE).stdout.read()
```

Answer (score 0):

```
try:
    response = client.describe_instance_patches(InstanceId=instance_id, Filters=[{'Key': 'State','Values': ['Installed',]} ])
except OverflowError:
    //handle the exception as you want. Print a log, ignore, whatever.
```

Comment: I can't ignore it, I need to get the patches anyway